# How to check if username is already taken, PostgreSQL and php

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I need to сheck if username is already taken or not. And if it is ok, to redirect to another page but if not (here I am stuck) to make the "username is already taken" appear under the input line.

there is my php code:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$dbusername = "postgres";
$dbpassword = "admroot";
$db = "local_db_server_test";
$con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$dbusername password=$dbpassword") or die ("Could not connect to Server\n");
    if(!$con){ die('Error: Unable to open database');   } 
    else {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
            if(strlen($password) < 6) {
                pg_close($con); // also can use die() but without header and redirection 
                header("Location:sign_up_pass_err.html");
            } 
        $query = "INSERT INTO register(username, password) VALUES ('$username',crypt('$password',gen_salt('md5')))";
        $result = pg_query($con, $query);
        header("Location: login.html");
    }
pg_close($con);

?>
```

And this is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head></head> 
    <body>
        <form action="sign_up.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required><br><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Before insert, write query to SELECT where username = $username, if row exists, then throw error

Comment: Don't forget to escape the quotes. You have SQL injection vulnerability

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene how to throw error? I wrote correctly? ||| 
$query ="select username from register where username=$username"; "INSERT INTO register(username, password) VALUES ('$username',crypt('$password',gen_salt('md5')))";

Comment: Why did you edit the question adding the code from the answer?

Comment: The NervousDev, said it was more easier to find error, "that will be much more easy", I turned it back

Comment: There is no need to check. Place a *Unique Constraint* on username then just insert when needed. If it already exists Postgres will throw “duplicate key violates unique constraint* exception. Handle the exception as necessary.

Comment: @Belayer way is the proper one, to avoid entry of duplicate row and must be done before production. My answer is based on question. Can you help me with what does this line do in your code.   if(!$con){ die('Error: Unable to open database');   }

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene this line in code is doing: "if you can't connect to database your script die, ends here and throw error, Error: Unable to open database"